# FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly in WebRole (recycling instance)

Tags: azure, autofac, azure-web-roles, azure-cloud-services

My WebRole won't start but keeps restarting and throws this exception:

```
Application: WaIISHost.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: 
 System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Autofac, Version=3.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=17863af14b0044da' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
File name: 'Autofac, Version=3.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=17863af14b0044da'
   at MyDomain.Web.AutofacWebModule.Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
   at Autofac.Module.Configure(IComponentRegistry componentRegistry)
   at Autofac.ContainerBuilder.Build(IComponentRegistry componentRegistry, Boolean excludeDefaultModules)
   at Autofac.ContainerBuilder.Build(ContainerBuildOptions options)
   at MyDomain.Web.Startup.BuildAutofacContainer() in MyDomain.Web\Startup.cs:line 82
   at MyDomain.Web.WebRole.Run() in MyDomain.Web\WebRole.cs:line 25
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.StartRoleInternal()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.Implementation.Loader.RoleRuntimeBridge.<StartRole>b__2()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

UPDATE. Added a full error description with the help of this article:
[Troubleshooting Scenario 7 – Role Recycling](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kwill/2013/10/03/troubleshooting-scenario-7-role-recycling/)

UPDATE 2. Found a good article about the exception. [Cloud Services roles recycling with the error “System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly”](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cie/2015/09/06/cloud-services-roles-recycling-with-the-error-system-io-fileloadexception-could-not-load-file-or-assembly/#comment-1503). It seems to be enough to fix the problem.

The reason it breaks is on my Azure instance, in `E:\approot\bin\` there is no `MyDomain.Web.config` files with the redirections required by Autofac. And the `web.config` in `E:\approot\` is not read by the `WaIISHost.exe`. And so it breaks.

Comment: Are you sure that your are not referencing different Autofac versions in your project?

Comment: @Jeroen Looks like I do. The point is to get those `bindingRedirection`s working though. Please see the update.

Answer (score 0):

It needed the `<role name>.dll.config` file added to solution (same level as the web.config or app.config) (the Copy to Output Directory property to “Copy Always”). Then redeploying to Azure. This file should contain the `bindingRedirect` settings.