# Attempt to load wrong Autofac assembly in Wix bootstrapper project

Tags: c#, wpf, wix, autofac

I’m building a WPF UI to use with bootstrapper on an install. The WPF UI uses Autofac for DI, and the common service locator.

Everything compiles correctly, but when I try to access any of the Autofac-registered types:

```
public static ILogger Logger => ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ILogger>();
public static IWixViewModel WixViewModel => ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IWixViewModel>();
```

I get the following exception:

> System.IO.FileLoadException occurred   HResult=0x80131040
>   Message=Could not load file or assembly 'Autofac, Version=3.5.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=17863af14b0044da' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>   Source=Olbert.Wix.MinimalUI   StackTrace:    at
>   Olbert.Wix.ViewModels.WixLocator.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.cctor>b__5()
>   in C:\Programming\LanHistory\WixUI\viewmodels\WixLocator.cs:line 99
>   at Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocator.get_Current()
>   at Olbert.Wix.ViewModels.WixLocator.get_WixViewModel() in
>   C:\Programming\LanHistory\WixUI\viewmodels\WixLocator.cs:line 103
>   at Olbert.Wix.WixApp.Run() in
>   C:\Programming\LanHistory\WixUI\WixApp.cs:line 28    at
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    at
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

What's confusing me is that nowhere in any of the projects in this solution do I reference anything other than Autofac 4.5. So why is something trying to load v3.5? AFAIK, the WIX toolset doesn't use Autofac, so I don't think that's the source of the problem.

Here's my bundle.wxs file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Bundle Name="LanHistoryBootstrapper" 
          Version="0.5.0.0" 
          Manufacturer="Jump for Joy Software" 
          UpgradeCode="1db721ec-d675-4e60-a55b-d134497a5a35">
    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="ManagedBootstrapperApplicationHost">
      <Payload SourceFile="$(var.LanHistorySetupUI.TargetDir)Olbert.LanHistorySetupUI.dll"/>

      <Payload SourceFile="$(var.LanHistorySetupUI.TargetDir)\Autofac.dll" />
      <Payload SourceFile="$(var.LanHistorySetupUI.TargetDir)\Autofac.Extras.CommonServiceLocator.dll" />
      <Payload SourceFile="$(var.LanHistorySetupUI.TargetDir)\BootstrapperCore.dll" />
      <Payload SourceFile="$(var.LanHistorySetupUI.TargetDir)\GalaSoft.MvvmLight.dll" />
      <Payload SourceFile="$(var.LanHistorySetupUI.TargetDir)\GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.dll" />
      <Payload SourceFile="$(var.LanHistorySetupUI.TargetDir)\GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.pdb" />
      <Payload SourceFile="$(var.LanHistorySetupUI.TargetDir)\GalaSoft.MvvmLight.pdb" />
      <Payload SourceFile="$(var.LanHistorySetupUI.TargetDir)\GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Platform.dll" />
      <Payload SourceFile="$(var.LanHistorySetupUI.TargetDir)\GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Platform.pdb" />
      <Payload SourceFile="$(var.LanHistorySetupUI.TargetDir)\Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.dll" />
      <Payload SourceFile="$(var.LanHistorySetupUI.TargetDir)\Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.pdb" />
      <Payload SourceFile="$(var.LanHistorySetupUI.TargetDir)\Olbert.j4j.UI.dll" />
      <Payload SourceFile="$(var.LanHistorySetupUI.TargetDir)\Olbert.j4j.UI.pdb" />
      <Payload SourceFile="$(var.LanHistorySetupUI.TargetDir)\Olbert.Wix.MinimalUI.dll" />
      <Payload SourceFile="$(var.LanHistorySetupUI.TargetDir)\Olbert.Wix.MinimalUI.dll.config" />
      <Payload SourceFile="$(var.LanHistorySetupUI.TargetDir)\Olbert.Wix.MinimalUI.pdb" />
      <Payload SourceFile="$(var.LanHistorySetupUI.TargetDir)\Serilog.dll" />
      <Payload SourceFile="$(var.LanHistorySetupUI.TargetDir)\Serilog.Sinks.File.dll" />
      <Payload SourceFile="$(var.LanHistorySetupUI.TargetDir)\Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile.dll" />
      <Payload SourceFile="$(var.LanHistorySetupUI.TargetDir)\System.Windows.Interactivity.dll" />

      <Payload SourceFile="$(var.LanHistorySetupUI.TargetDir)BootstrapperCore.config"/>
    </BootstrapperApplicationRef>

        <Chain>
            <!-- TODO: Define the list of chained packages. -->
            <!-- <MsiPackage SourceFile="path\to\your.msi" /> -->

      <PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx462Web"/>
      <MsiPackage SourceFile="$(var.LanHistorySetup.TargetDir)LanHistorySetup.msi" />
        </Chain>
    </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

And here's the BootstrapperCore.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- Copyright (c) .NET Foundation and contributors. All rights reserved. Licensed under the Microsoft Reciprocal License. See LICENSE.TXT file in the project root for full license information. -->


<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="wix.bootstrapper" type="Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.Bootstrapper.BootstrapperSectionGroup, BootstrapperCore">
            <section name="host" type="Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.Bootstrapper.HostSection, BootstrapperCore" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" />
        <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727" />
    </startup>
    <wix.bootstrapper>
        <!-- Example only. Use only if the startup/supportedRuntime above cannot discern supported frameworks. -->
        <!--
        <supportedFramework version="v4\Client" />
        <supportedFramework version="v3.5" />
        <supportedFramework version="v3.0" />
        -->

        <!-- Example only. Replace the host/@assemblyName attribute with assembly that implements BootstrapperApplication. -->
        <host assemblyName="Olbert.LanHistorySetupUI" />
    </wix.bootstrapper>
</configuration>
```

The app.config file for the WPF UI component is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Autofac" publicKeyToken="17863af14b0044da" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.5.0.0" newVersion="4.5.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Windows.Interactivity" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2" /></startup></configuration>
```

Comment: Do you perhaps have Autofac in the GAC on the machine you're trying to install on? Maybe one of these will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37734742/autofac-exception-could-not-load-type-from-assembly (GAC issue)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26277008/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-autofac-version-3-3-0-0 (version issue)

Comment: Thanx, Brian. But Autofac isn't in the GAC.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, you must also add your assembly binding redirects to BootstrapperCore.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- Copyright (c) .NET Foundation and contributors. All rights reserved. Licensed under the Microsoft Reciprocal License. See LICENSE.TXT file in the project root for full license information. -->


<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="wix.bootstrapper" type="Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.Bootstrapper.BootstrapperSectionGroup, BootstrapperCore">
            <section name="host" type="Microsoft.Tools.WindowsInstallerXml.Bootstrapper.HostSection, BootstrapperCore" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" />
        <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727" />
    </startup>
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Autofac" publicKeyToken="17863af14b0044da" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.5.0.0" newVersion="4.5.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Windows.Interactivity" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
    <wix.bootstrapper>
        <!-- Example only. Use only if the startup/supportedRuntime above cannot discern supported frameworks. -->
        <!--
        <supportedFramework version="v4\Client" />
        <supportedFramework version="v3.5" />
        <supportedFramework version="v3.0" />
        -->

        <!-- Example only. Replace the host/@assemblyName attribute with assembly that implements BootstrapperApplication. -->
        <host assemblyName="Olbert.LanHistorySetupUI" />
    </wix.bootstrapper>
</configuration>
```

If it does not help, you may try to handle `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve` event to provide the correct assembly.